# Content Blocks - 'unsecure elements'

Tags: orocommerce

I'm attempting to customise the layout of a Content Block, and when trying to add further elements to the HTML structure (e.g adding text, changing the CSS classes) I get the following error message.

> The entered content is not permitted in this field. Please remove the
> potentially unsecure elements, or contact the system administrators to
> lift the restrictions.

What causes this message to trigger? And is there anyway to get around it? We're using OroCommerce 4.1.1 on CentOS with Nginx (via Azure Marketplace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message was improved in further versions and now has more details on what is wrong with the input and how to fix the error. We recommend upgrading to the latest available version, 4.1.11.

To upgrade the application, you can follow the official guide:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/upgrade-to-new-version/